# Extracting timestamp and window from PCAP file and saving as text file

Tags: python

[image: PCAP file]

I would like to extract timestamp (unix time) and window values from a PCAP file and save as text file separated by commas:

```
timestamp,window
```

I trying using pypcapfile:

```
 from pcapfile import savefile

testcap = open('/home/krsna/Desktop/1.pcap', 'rb')

capfile = savefile.load_savefile(testcap, verbose=True)


print (capfile.packets[0].__dir__())

print (capfile.packets[0].timestamp)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Easier would be to use `tshark` (the command line program).  Something like `tshark -r FILE ...` - I'm sure you can figure out how to specify which field you want to print (hint: it shows the name of the field in Wireshark's status bar when you select a field in the details pane).

Comment: @John Zwinck: thanks! I will try!

Comment: @John Zwinck: Is that possible to save timestamp and TCP windows size in CSV format? I tried but I was not able to do it!

Comment: tshark -r "1.pcap" -Tfields -e frame.time_epoch -e tcp.window_size_value >> arquivo.txt